# Move uploaded file - no permissions

Tags: php, linux, apache, upload

I keep getting a permissions error when uploading files.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/localhost/htdocs/trade-show/documents/hero_front.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/trade-show/selectItems.php on line 30

Here is my code. The only way to get it to work is by making the directory permissions 777. I have tried chmod 0755 with no luck. Thoughts?

```
if ($_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == 0) {
    $upload = "/var/www/localhost/htdocs/trade-show/documents/".basename($_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],$upload)) {
        echo "<h1>Error uploading file ".$_FILES['fileUpload']['name']."</h1>$upload<br />\n";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],$upload);
    }
}
```

Comment: given changing to 777 fixes the problem, it's a permissions issue. you need to check the ownership of the destination and remember that this code will be running under the userID of the webserver. As well, what is the point of the `if (!move()) { move() }` code? If the move succeeds, you try to move it again and will get a "no such file" error because there's no more file to move.

Comment: When you refer to the ownership of the destination, you are referring to the documents folder I have set up. I think I have tried this in my terminal. How would I check the ownership?

Comment: `ls -ld /var/.../documents`

Comment: I believe that is directory -read - write - execute, execute - read, execute.

Comment: that's 755 as expected. you need to check the ownership, which tell you which users/groups the `7` and `5` apply to